# Is JsonMessageConverter thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I want to create `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter` as a Singleton Spring bean and autowire it in my services. Is it thread-safe?

Comment: Spring bean in and of itself is not thread safe so my natural inclination would be no. You can change the scope to not be singleton though which makes it a possible yes.

Comment: @WhyCry I should reword the question but I'm interested in if JsonMessageConverter is thread-safe to make it singleton scoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's threadsafe to use, assuming you use it in a threadsafe way. E.g. if you call `setJsonObjectMapper(...)` on it, it will affect all threads that use it.